# Color coded plot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a color coded plot. Here is a part of the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
color_scheme = plt.get_cmap('cool')
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
gs.update(left=0.15,bottom=0.15,right=0.80,top=0.95)
cax = fig.add_axes([0.80, 0.15, 0.03, 0.80])

im = ax1.scatter(x, y, c=z, edgecolors='black', marker='.', s=40, lw=1, cmap=color_scheme, vmin=0, vmax=10)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
for t in cb.ax.get_yticklabels(): t.set_fontsize(12)
```

The problem is that I want to connect the dots with a line, and it doesn't work to use marker='-' and it also doesn't work if I use ax1.plt. How can I do this?
What I actually need is to fit a line to some points and color it the same color as the points (the points I fit to will all have same color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
ax1.scatter(x, y, ...)
```

use

```
ax1.plot(x, y, 'o-', ...) # three dots meaning you can configure markers, linestyle, etc.
```

This works bacause of `'o-'` argument, which is a line plot with markers at every data point.

Comment: Does this really work?  I am not sure if the standard plot can handle colormaps.

Comment: As I say plt.plot doesn't handle colormaps

Comment: You are right about the colormaps. But how you expect the lines connecting the dots to be colored? If you want a single-colored line, you could plot it using `plot` and then overlay the colormapped markers using a subsequent call to `scatter`. Now if you want each line segment to be colored, then you would have to `plot` each segment independently, or use matplotlib shapes for that (not fast).

Answer (score 1):

Plot the same x and y-data separately with a standard `ax.plot` behind your scatter plot.

```
ax1.plot(x, y, '-')
im = ax1.scatter(x, y, c=z, edgecolors='black', marker='.', s=40, lw=1, cmap=color_scheme, vmin=0, vmax=10)
```

This should give you your cmapped scatter plot with the lines behind the scatter-points.

Comment: But if I do that, will the line has the same color distribution as the plot? I think it will be just blue

Comment: The default is ofcourse blue, and as you point out `plot` does not handle cmaps afaik.  However I thought the main goal was to just connect the points?

Comment: What I actually need is to fit a line to some points and color it the same color as the points (the points I fit to will all have same color).